# Note taking with LaTeX syntax and images

Tags: osx, note-taking

I'm looking for a note-taking app in which I can both (i) write equations with LaTeX syntax, and (ii) paste in images without saving them to a file first.

The first of these can be done with any Markdown editor. I currently use the Markdown+Math extension for VS Code, which works well for (i) but doesn't seem to support images. Other Markdown editors may support images, but I don't want to have to save them as a file and write Markdown code to include then. Instead I'd like to just take a screen shot and then add it to the notes with CMD-V, as I would in a Stack Exchange post, and have the image saved automatically alongside the text.

Here's a list of my requirements, including the above two plus a few more.

- Supports LaTeX syntax for equations (e.g. via KaTeX or MathJax)
- Supports adding images with CMD-V, without requiring them to be saved separately
- Uncluttered user interface
- Free or relatively inexpensive
- **not** web based
- **not** subscription based
- Runs on Mac OS X <s>10.11</s> 10.15

<sub>(A previous version of this question specified OS X 10.11, but I decided to take the plunge and upgrade over the Christmas period, so more 'modern' apps are ok now too.)</sub>

Comment: It willl not completely answer your request, but you can take notes in markdown, inserting in it latex equations and then generate latex/pdf/htlm with pandoc sofware. I have just tested Typora software: it allows to insert images in markdown file by copy and paste or by sliding an image. Worth being tested in my opinion.

Comment: @Damien Markdown-based is fine - I use Markdown already, as I mentioned in the question. Typora looks great and is probably worth an answer, but unfortunately for me it needs OS X 10.13.4 or higher.

Comment: Sorry, as you mentioned Latex in the title, I thought you wanted to use it instead of markdown. Typora site mentions a beta version for OS X 10.13.4, not for older versions effectively

Comment: @Damien I've edited the title to make it clear I only need LaTeX syntax, not LaTeX itself. I'd actually prefer a MathJax or KaTeX solution (via Markdown or otherwise), since they're faster.

Answer (score 1):

The [Desktop Wiki zim](https://zim-wiki.org/) is written in python and fulfills all your requirements.

You can write text quickly with a minimal markup and use LaTeX for Formulas.
Have a look at the nice screenshots on https://zim-wiki.org/screenshots.html
[image: https://github.com/zim-desktop-wiki/zim-desktop-wiki/blob/master/website/files/screenshots/zim-equation-editor-2.png]

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing a self-answer, based on the suggestion by Damien in the comments of **Typora**. Here are some pros and cons. (The cons are all very minor and most of them might get fixed, since it's in beta currently.)

Pros:

- It's exactly what I was looking for - a Markdown-based note taking app with an uncluttered UI that supports LaTeX syntax (via MathJax) and lets you paste in images.
- It supports various syntaxes for drawing diagrams, which is actually pretty handy for me.
- It supports using `\newcommand` in LaTeX code, which then applies throughout the file. (This doesn't work in VS Code.)

Cons:

- It's free while it's in Beta, but there's no indication of how much it will cost after that.
- Text entry and editing behaves subtly differently from other MacOS apps sometimes. (e.g. it automatically inserts a paragraph break when pressing enter, which I don't like at all, but I'll get used to it.)
- No option to change the delimiters for maths mode - it's $ and $$ or nothing.

By default it saves images in a central folder in `~/Application Support`, but you can change it to save them in a local `[filename].assets` folder, which I find more future-proof.

Basically, Typora is a very good solution.